# VisualDiffItems doesn't run as modal

Tags: c#, tfs

TFS SDK have a [VisualDiffItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh715283(v=vs.120).aspx) function with a parameter to run it as modal window. I have my custom external tool set in tfs settings and it runs well and accepts two files as a parameters. But it is not modal. Code executes after the function call and does not wait until external tool will be closed.

If i run `tf.exe diff` tool will be modal.

Below is the code sample I'm using. Whatever I pass to the function as `modal` parameter result is the same. What I'm expecting is that when `modal == true` the external tool will be started and program will wait for it to be closed before it advances execution past last line. In other words synchronously wait for `VisualDiffItems` execution.

```
    public void Diff(string sourceFile, bool latest, bool modal)
    {
        VersionSpec version = latest ? version = VersionSpec.Latest : new WorkspaceVersionSpec(workSpace);
        var diffItem1 = new DiffItemVersionedFile(VCS, sourceFile, version);
        var diffItem2 = new DiffItemLocalFile(sourceFile, Encoding.UTF8.CodePage, DateTime.Now, false);
        Difference.VisualDiffItems(VCS, diffItem1, diffItem2, modal);
    }
```

Acceptable answer would be if someone could explain what does that quote from MSDN means.

> Whether the diff should come up in a modal experience.

Comment: What's that mean run as modal? Could you please share the detail steps and code sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: modalExperience the data type is `Boolean`. So your understanding is correct.. Whatever try reference this article to use the `Difference.VisualDiffItems` method: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmanning/2006/03/27/programmatically-showing-differences-between-files/

Comment: @Andy-MSFT thanks. I saw it. It doesn't explain why VisualDiffItems call is async.